# Put files to home directory

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, debian

I trying to "debianization" my small programm. My programm has "templates" directory. This folder contains the files the user is working with. The user will also store their files in this directory. But all these operations are done by my program, and I want to hide this folder in the "HOME" directory. But I do not understand how this can be done with the debianization of the package? I can create a bash script that will create the necessary folders for me, but how can I transfer an already prepared folder with files to a package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `deb` package can only install things in `/usr` and configuration files in `/etc`. You generally should not modify users' home directories during installation; packages might create customizations for individual users if and when they interact with the installed package e.g. by running an installed utility for the first time.

Obvious workarounds such as looping over all individual users' home directories from the `postinst` or `configure` script violate Debian policy, create unpleasant surprises, and obviously don't work for users whose accounts are created after the package was installed.